# How do I disable use of a particular gem in a two gems, one library situation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, rubygems

I have two rubygems "spreadsheet" and "spreadsheet-excel" installed in my system. Both of them are different but their method of initializing it is the same.

For example, I want to use spreadsheet-excel in my rails application but when I do a 'require spreadsheet/excel', apparently it loads the files from the spreadsheet gem and not spreadsheet-excel even though the instructions are the same.

How can I disable a particular gem from a single rails application?

I need both gems because I have another application that uses the 'spreadsheet' gem and spreadsheet-excel is for a legacy application I'm supporting

The application is running on Rails 2.3.8.

Answer (score 1):

I would make use of RVM and gemsets for this sort of task. Gemsets allow you to compartmentalize a set of gems. You can load up different gemsets at any time. Checkout the basics on [gemsets](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/basics/).

Comment: Thanks raidfive, but I cannot install RVM on my client's system due to IT bureaucracy. Is there anyway out?

Comment: Dang, that sounds like a pain :/ Sounds like most of the solutions proposed won't work for you. Hopefully someone has another solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Gemfile file in every rails 3 project. You can specify your gems there.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear in my original post, the application is a 2.3.8 app. I've edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: While `bundler` may not be baked into Rails 2 there is no reason it cannot be used there.  I think there is even some documentation on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the bundler Gem.  It comes standard in Rails 3 but **it can still be used in Rails 2.3**.  Yehuda Katz explains how to make this work here:  http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/03/using-the-new-gem-bundler-today/

Comment: Thanks John for the suggestion but my client's IT vendor wouldn't allow me to install a new gem without going through tons of paperwork :(